# "rte_eth_tx_burst" causes segmentation fault error (dpdk)

Tags: c, dpdk

I wanna receive packets from two ports by a server, then sends to some clients, then clients send them back to the server, then again the server sends them back to one of the ports.

I have modified one of the dpdk's example named "client_server_mp", explained [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/multi_process.html).

The example is designated to receive some packets from ethernet ports, then sends them to some clients; then clients send the received packets to the ports again. I made some modification to change this procedure; as clients send the packets back to the server again and the sever sends them to the ports. For that purpose I made tx rings between server and clients in addition to the previous rx rings. I added some lines of code into init_shm_rings() function to make tx rings:

```
static int
init_shm_rings(void)
{
    unsigned i;
    unsigned socket_id;
    const char * qrx_name;
    const char * qtx_name;
    const unsigned ringsize = CLIENT_QUEUE_RINGSIZE;

    clients = rte_malloc("client details",
        sizeof(*clients) * num_clients, 0);
    if (clients == NULL)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot allocate memory for client program details\n");


for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {
        /* Create TX RX queue for each client */
        socket_id = rte_socket_id();
        
        /* RX ring */
        qrx_name = get_rx_queue_name(i);
        clients[i].rx_q = rte_ring_create(qrx_name,
                ringsize, socket_id,
                 RING_F_SC_DEQ ); /* multiple prod, single cons */
        if (clients[i].rx_q == NULL){
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create rx ring queue for client %u\n", i);
        }

        /* TX ring (newly added by me) */
        qtx_name = get_tx_queue_name(i);
        clients[i].tx_q = rte_ring_create(qtx_name,
                ringsize, socket_id,
                RING_F_SP_ENQ | RING_F_SC_DEQ ); /* single prod, single cons */
        if (clients[i].tx_q == NULL){
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create tx ring queue for client %u\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Also, I made two rx rings for every port and used this configuration for them:

```
static const struct rte_eth_conf port_conf_default = {
    .rxmode = {
        .mq_mode = RTE_ETH_MQ_RX_RSS,
    },
    .rx_adv_conf = {
        .rss_conf = {
            .rss_hf = RTE_ETH_RSS_IP | RTE_ETH_RSS_UDP |
                RTE_ETH_RSS_TCP | RTE_ETH_RSS_SCTP,
        }
    },
};
```

This is the problem; server sends packets to the clients by means of **process_packets()** function from main example, then receives returned packets from the client's rings successfully by means of **rte_ring_dequeue_burst()** function; but once when the server wants to sends back the packets to the ports by means of **rte_eth_tx_burst()** function, "Segmentation Fault" error arises.**Interestingly, some packets are received from clients before crashing of the server side.**

I used "address sanitizer" to check memory related problems and it shows me **"heap overflow"** problem.

Client side works fine and the modification to the main program is restricted to the main function and the main function's eternal loop; Also I commented out the port configuration as I don't wanna client sends the packets to the ports' rings. Here is the modification I made in client's program eternal loop in the main function:

```
for (;;) {
        uint16_t rx_pkts = rte_ring_dequeue_burst(rx_ring, pkts,
                PKT_READ_SIZE, NULL);
        rx_stats.rx += rx_pkts;]
                /* send the packets back to the server (newly added by me to the example) */
        if(rx_pkts > 0){
                uint16_t tx_pkts = rte_ring_enqueue_burst(tx_ring, pkts, sizeof(pkts), NULL);
                if(tx_pkts < rx_pkts){
                    for(int i = tx_pkts ; i < rx_pkts ; i++){
                        rte_pktmbuf_free(pkts[i]);
                    }
                    tx_stats.tx_drop += (rx_pkts - tx_pkts);
                }
                tx_stats.tx += tx_pkts;
            }
}
```

Some important information:

DPDK version: 21.11.1 - OS: Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-128-generic. I work on a VM which uses 2 vmxnet3 virtual ethernet ports; you can see the necessary info about this NIC [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html). There are 2 ethernet ports with 2 rx rings and 1 tx ring for each one. Rx rings are in RSS mode with hash method based on RTE_ETH_RSS_IP, RTE_ETH_RSS_UDP, RTE_ETH_RSS_TCP, and RTE_ETH_RSS_SCTP; tx mode is in default config.
I used the default offload flags for each ring.

I will appreciate anyone who can show me a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: please always make it a habit to share DPDK version, os or distro with kernel version, Nic in use, firmware, offload flags set to the NIC. if there is a segment fault core dump or back track. Steps to reproduce the error. If it is related to tx packet use packet dump to dump the rte_mbuf contents too.

Comment: I added the mentioned information. Can you explain more?
@VipinVarghese

Comment: still missing details `if there is a segment fault core dump or back track. Steps to reproduce the error. If it is related to tx packet use packet dump to dump the rte_mbuf contents too`

Comment: still waiting for you to share the back trace for segfault and pkt_mbuf_dump for the packet before calling tx_burst

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I solved the problem. I made mistake in client side. As you can see in the last code section in my question, I used the "rte_ring_enqueue_burst" to send back the packets from client and sizeof(pkts) as one of its elements. The "sizeof()" does not return the actual size of the pointer array, it returns size as bytes. So the specified size was wrong and I think because of that, server confused to recognize packet objects on membuf.
@VipinVarghese

Comment: I'm gonna add the complete answer and explanation as soon as possible.
@VipinVarghese

Comment: @MohammadKhaledi follow up, it is been 10 days since you have posted in comment `The "sizeof()" does not return the actual size of the pointer array, it returns size as bytes.`. there is no answer update from your end, so please do the same or close this question